# When holding Alt + Tab, how to prevent the Q key from closing applications?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (and holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to keep the  application-level windows in view), the <kbd>Q</kbd> key immediately closes all windows of the highlighted application. Firefox for instance doesn't ask for confirmation<sup>1</sup> — I prefer clearing all browsing data when closing the browser<sup>2</sup> and have lost several sessions ([profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles)) when accidentally hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> (which presumably is located next to <kbd>Tab</kbd> on most keyboard layouts).

I don't have any real use for this Gnome shortcut and would only benefit from disabling it entirely.

<sup>1</sup> 'Confirm before quitting with Ctrl+Q' in the Firefox settings
<sup>2</sup> 'Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed' in the Firefox settings

---

Gnome 43.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as a new Gnome user and it drove me mad not finding this in the Gnome settings for keyboard shortcuts. I've always had Super+Q to close windows previously.

Anyway, I found a solution from a Reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/cefws9/how_do_i_disable_ctrlq_shortcut_closing_apps/) to disable this default action. Apparently it's implemented by Gnome apps and not the window manager.

To override it, you can create a custom keyboard shortcut that maps Ctrl+Q to something benign like the `true` command which does nothing and returns successfully. See `man 1 true`.

[image: Gnome settings config]

Comment: You appear to have addressed the Ctrl+Q hotkey. I was asking about [the Gnome window switcher](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-switching.html.en) (Alt+Tab / Super+Tab).

Comment: @user598527 Ah, sorry I missed that. Btw this happens on my system too. Perhaps you could reassign the default shortcut for switching windows so you don't accidentally end up pressing Q.